# Is it possible to animate SVG path without use of stroke ?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

There is my svg:

```html
<svg class="num-frame" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="326.229px" height="242.623px" viewBox="0 0 326.229 242.623" enable-background="new 0 0 326.229 242.623" xml:space="preserve">

  <g id="Layer_1">
    <g id="Layer_1_1_">
      <path class="pathe" stroke-width="4" d="M268.971,60.112c-82.83-148.908-248.519,111.12-145.339,150.875c80.484,30.996,200.946-39.396,168.728-132.591
       C261.292-11.486,94.387,6.078,87.437,102.417c-7.715,106.967,139.807,153.589,213.991,93.134c0.709-0.575-0.242-1.804-0.982-1.27
       c-59.93,43.702-153.784,28.327-194.988-34.033c-36.732-55.58,0.429-114.795,58.131-131.517
       C223.1,11.48,289.667,41.227,294.159,107.434c4.34,63.967-59.375,93.766-112.195,103.209
       c-33.778,6.039-74.836,1.325-84.991-36.949c-7.695-28.985,5.878-62.127,19.867-86.895c34.6-61.241,105.552-97.912,150.95-26
       C268.258,61.552,269.403,60.889,268.971,60.112L268.971,60.112z" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I need to make an animation, that will look like hand drawing this circle (line animation), I know have to make it with help of stroke but than the path will lost it's orginal shape, so I want animate orginal shape (path) in way like with stroke.

Answer (score 1):

You could make put a simpler path on top of that one with a white stroke, and use the 2nd path's stroke-dasharray to do the animation that reveals the path underneath.

By simpler, I mean that the 2nd path would have a single stroke and no fill.  Just make sure the stroke-width is wide enough to cover the widest part of the path underneath.